# Keep select HTML element consistent when changing theme in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

As you see [![here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5PYh.png) there is a visual difference when changing themes in Firefox to the native Select html element. On the left we have the system theme, whose options background is white-ish when expanded. On the right is the dark theme, whose options list has now a dark background.

That is to be expected of course, but is there anything that can be set with CSS or JS to force the element to stay unaffected from an alternative theme and be rendered according to the System Theme? Business clients like very much consistent layouts..

PS: I am using Firefox 89.0b15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might work if you manually change the background color of the option.

Comment: Hehe, I can't believe I didn't check that. What actually helped was setting the background-color in Select itself. Kudos @boris-nl

Comment: No problem, mind setting the question as answered?